# No se ve el recuento de votos en la versión móvil

Tags: bug, privilegios, web-móvil

Quería ver el recuento de votos (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) de una pregunta y en la versión móvil (Chrome) no se puede ver haciendo "tap" en el número de votos de la pregunta/respuesta.

- Versión de Chrome: 85.0.4183.101
- Sistema operativo: Android 9

¿Es un fallo conocido?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás logado? ¿Te refieres a la versión móvil o a la versión completa pero responsive?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' si, estoy logueado, de hecho puedo votar positivo/negativo. No se responderte al tipo de versión, he pegado una captura. Se supone que es la página web tal como la muestra Chrome, sin instalar ninguna aplicación especial.

Comment: Esto lo escribo desde el móvil para verificar que estoy logueado.

Comment: Publicaciones relevantes (en ingles): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370047/579895 y https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341064/346768

Comment: Aunque no termina de estar claro, parece que en la versión responsive de la web, si debería funcionar